# Hello android sudoku to check if the game is complete to display a dialog box

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sudoku

I am trying to display a dialog box in the hello Android Sudoku example but when I run the app nothing happens. In the game.java I check if the puzzle is solved like this

```
/******Check to see if the game is complete**/
   public boolean isSolved()
   {
       for (int element : puzzle) {
           if (element == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;           
   }
```

Then in the PuzzleView in the onKeyDown method i try to detect if isSolved is true and if it is display the dialog

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (game.isSolved() == true) {
        Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, Congratulations.class);
        getContext().startActivity(i);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown: keycode=" + keyCode + ", event=" + event);
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            select(selX, selY - 1);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            select(selX, selY + 1);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            select(selX - 1, selY);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            select(selX + 1, selY);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE:
            setSelectedTile(0);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
            setSelectedTile(1);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:
            setSelectedTile(2);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
            setSelectedTile(3);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4:
            setSelectedTile(4);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5:
            setSelectedTile(5);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6:
            setSelectedTile(6);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7:
            setSelectedTile(7);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8:
            setSelectedTile(8);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9:
            setSelectedTile(9);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;

}
```

I am learning java and Android development so please any help as to where I am going wrong will be much appreciated. If anyone needs more information please just ask and I will put it in an edit section for the question.

Comment: It will be difficult to figure out the problem when we have no idea whats in the variable puzzle.

Comment: Would you like me to post the whole game class and the whole puzzleview class?

Comment: No need because it is lots of code. Just wanted to know if isSolved() returns true. You can check if by putting a log there.

Comment: @LazyNinja how would I go about doing that? Im sorry I am completely new to Java and eclipse

Comment: By dialog do you mean Activity? Because you are starting an activity whereas Android provides some pretty simple builder classes for pre-designed dialogs. See AlertDialog.Builder for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the way I checked to see if the game was complete was to have this in the game.class

```
/****** Check to see if the game is complete **/
public boolean isSolved() {
    for (int element : puzzle) {
        if (element == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And also

```
public boolean checkIsSolved()
{
    //check if the game is complete after each valid move
    if (isSolved() == true) { 
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Congratulations.class); 
        startActivity(i);} 
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WillNZ this is not answer, just to show you how put the log

```
/******Check to see if the game is complete**/
   public boolean isSolved()
   {
       for (int element : puzzle) {
           if (element == 0) return false;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", " isSolved() is true");
        return true;           
   }
```

Run your application and see if you can see " isSolved() is true" in your logcat.

Comment: Ok I ran this in debug mode and did not see isSolved in the logcat.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know. The problem is not about the dialog display. Since the isSolved() never returns true, your dialog activity won't be called. Okay on onKeyDown() method change if (game.isSolved() == true)  to if( true ) . This will launch the dialog everytime you press a key, but you can check if your dialog is showing up.

Comment: Ok so the dialog didnot show up and the code ofter the else statement was underlined with the message "Dead code" options "remove (including condition)" and "Add @SuppressWarnings 'unsed' to 'onKeyDown()'

Comment: Ignore the warnings for the moment.It is just for test purpose. Have you registered Congratulations activity in your manifest file? If yes replace Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, Congratulations.class); with Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Congratulations.class);

Comment: Yes it is registered in the manifest file. I now have `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  //if (game.isSolved() == true) {
  if (true) {
   //Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, Congratulations.class);
   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Congratulations.class); 
   getContext().startActivity(i);` which has an error on getApplicationContext

Comment: hmmm! Maybe you are not inside an activity. Are you using the same code as this one https://github.com/dmoulton/Android-Sudoku

Comment: Yes it looks to be the same. I am using the 3rd edition of the book.